# Dynamic Label Text within a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, label

I made a simple WF in C# in an attempt to change the label dynamically.

However, when I run this code, there is no visible change, until after the code has run, and then it changes to "Processing 9"  0-8 are not ever shown.  Is it because it is within the loop?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            label9.Text = "Processing " + i.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: X-Tech's code worked but when I tried to incorporate it into my code, I get the following threading issue. I am trying to dynamically change the label.text in the loop while the progress bar is rocking:

**An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued**

I am not sure how to attack this since I am not super familiar with Task.Factory.StartNew() and Invoke statements.

EDIT 2: Adapted Code:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < lstFilesToZip.Items.Count; i++)
      {
          zipArray[i] = lstFilesToZip.Items[i].ToString();
          // Report progress.
          ExecuteSecure(() => label9.Text = "Processing :" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lstFilesToZip.Items[i].ToString()));
          ExecuteSecure(() => progressBar1.PerformStep());

          string zipFileName = Path.GetFileName(zipArray[i]);
          string newFolder = txtDestinationFolder.Text + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipArray[i]);
          //check to see if a directory with the file name for the zip file already exists, if not, it will create it
          if (Directory.Exists(newFolder) == false)
          {
                DirectoryInfo newPath = Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder);
                if (lstCommonFiles.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                     //copies each file in the common file list to each new folder created, the boolean indicates that it will overwrite existing files (true) or won't (false)
                     for (int k = 0; k < lstCommonFiles.Items.Count; k++)
                     {
                          File.Copy(lstCommonFiles.Items[k].ToString(), (newFolder + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(commonArray[k])), true);
                     }
                }
                //adds the zip file into the folder as well
                File.Copy(zipArray[i], (newFolder + "\\" + zipFileName), true);

          }
    }

    if (txtCommonFiles.Text.Length <= 0)
    {
          string result = "There are no common files selected, would you still like to proceed?";
          DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show(result, "Common Files Missing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
          if (result1 == DialogResult.No)
          {
               return;
          }
    }
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(txtDestinationFolder.Text);

    // Grabs the folders in the newly created directory
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
          lstDestinationFinal.Items.Add(dir);

    //send sample file contents to preview window
    string[] sampleFiles = Directory.GetFiles(lstDestinationFinal.Items[0].ToString());

    //grabs the files
    foreach (string zipFiles in sampleFiles)
         lstSampleFile.Items.Add(zipFiles);

    ExecuteSecure(() =>tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2);
});
```

}

And the added Method:

```
 private void ExecuteSecure(Action action)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => action()));
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's because you're doing the work in the UI thread, so the UI is frozen until the method is done. Use a BackgroundWorker and its ReportProgress to update your label in real time.

Comment: @Darw1n34 On which line you are getting exception?

Comment: @X-TECH I think our wires crossed, I was thanking you and telling you it worked :)

Comment: @Darw1n34 You mean its working now?

Comment: @X-TECH Yes, thank you.

Comment: @Darw1n34 OK, enjoyee ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {              
          Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => label9.Text = "Processing " + i.ToString()));
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
});
```

EDIT:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
          // Any GUI control which you want to use within thread,
          // you need Invoke using GUI thread. I have declare a method below for this
          //Now use this method as
          ExecuteSecure(() => label9.Text = "Processing " + i);
          ExecuteSecure(() => progressBar1.Value = i * 10);
          //... other code etc.
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
});


//---
private void ExecuteSecure(Action action)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => action()));
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm kickin' it old school with the BackgroundWorker... :p

Comment: @x-tech Can you take a look at the edit I made to my OP, please?

Comment: @Darw1n34 I have edit my post, please check it. Now you need to put GUI controls to `ExecuteSecure` method to avoid `CrossThreadException`

Comment: @X-Tech that is what I was missing, I had been toying with the if(InvokeRequired) but was doing so within my loop, not as a separate method.

Comment: @X-TECH Thanks, I posted the relevant parts of my code.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Use a BackgroundWorker if you want your UI to be updated in real time, else all the work is done on the UI thread and it remains frozen until the work is over.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int limit = 10;
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += (s, ee) =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
            {
                bw.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        };
        bw.ProgressChanged += (s, ee) => label9.Text = "Processing" + ee.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        label9.Text = "Processing " + i.ToString();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Form1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will probably work, but it's a really poor practice.

Comment: This is a poor solution because it ties up the GUI for 10 seconds.  See @Kilazur's comment on the question for a tip on how to do it right.

Comment: @Kilazur - Will read up on the poor practice around Refresh(). This worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            label9.Text = "Processing " + i.ToString();
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This ties up the GUI thread for a second at a time, ten times, plus it uses `Application.DoEvents`, which is dangerous because it allows reentrance.  For example, what happens if the user clicks button1 again while waiting for the first click to be handled?  Better to use a BackgroundWorker and properly disable the appropriate controls.

Comment: Many years ago I asked this same question of an advanced developer and he gave me this answer. Of course you are supposed to use threading and do it correctly but at that time I was not that advanced and he understood that. Sometimes when starting to learn the answer cannot be to climb a mountain.

Comment: The accepted answer, posted by X-TECH, solves the OP's problem in fewer lines of code while avoiding both the hang and the `DoEvents` reentrance bug, and it is no harder to understand than your own.  (Try explaining to a beginner what `Application.DoEvents()` actually does.)